# R data frame from contents of a character vector

Tags: r, dataframe, character

I am working with a long character vector where each row is supposed to contain a small data frame. I created a function to clean the data and produce a string which would be ready to input to the `data.frame()` function. The output is as follows:

```
[1] "`demo/members/education_member` = c('High_school', 'High_school'), `demo/members/status` = c('Other', 'Other'), `demo/members/name` = c('Hans Solo', 'Luke Skywalker')"
```

I wanted to pass this output to `data.frame()` to obtain the following data frame (resulting from copying and pasting the unquoted output above and passing it to the `data.frame` function):

```
  demo.members.education_member demo.members.status demo.members.name
1                   High_school               Other         Hans Solo
2                   High_school               Other    Luke Skywalker
```

**Question**: What would be the best way to convert the contents of a character output into a R data frame?

Comment: While there might be a way to do this, I think there are better ways to transform your raw data into a clean dataframe. You should consider asking a separate question for that as well.

Comment: If you would add data.frame() to your string it would be relatively straightforward, is  there a reason you can't do that?  The code you have is not a valid r expression by itself so the parse functions error.

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast replies! Applying `eval(parse(text=paste('data.frame(', data, ')')))` to the raw data, as suggested by Shree and Elin, did the job very well and more efficiently. Thanks and all the best!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way but reiterating my comment - There is likely to be a better way to transform your raw data into a cleaned up dataframe.

```
x <- "`demo/members/education_member` = c('High_school', 'High_school'), `demo/members/status` = c('Other', 'Other'), `demo/members/name` = c('Hans Solo', 'Luke Skywalker')"

y <- paste0("data.frame(", x, ")")

eval(parse(text = y))

demo.members.education_member demo.members.status demo.members.name
1                   High_school               Other         Hans Solo
2                   High_school               Other    Luke Skywalker
```

Comment: Ok mine is almost the same but different enough that I'll leave it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way you can do it, if it is possible to add the data.frame() function to your string.   If not let me know and I'll delete.  This is a bit quick and dirty and uses `rlang` but you can make it better by not using base `eval` and instead figuring out the rlang quasiquotation stuff.

```
x <- "data.frame(
  'demomemberseducationmember' = c('High_school','High_school'), 
  'demomembersstatus' = c('Other', 'Other'), 
  'demmembersname' = c('Hans Solo', 'Luke Skywalker'))"
eval(rlang::parse_expr(x))
```